# Can one resume praying if interrupted when not in a minyan

Tags: tefilla, hefsek-interruption

Are there any sources that comment on what to do if one is interrupted in the middle of the process of Shacharit, mincha or ma'ariv prayers without a minyan? Is it necessary to resume praying from the start once the disturbance has finished, or merely to continue from where you were when able to?

Is, for example, it permissible to resume sachrit prayers

Comment: You should clarify what part of the prayer you were interrupted in, and from where you are thinking of restarting. Certainly you would not start over from the very beginning.

Comment: I agree with Ariel, there are different laws depending on what part of Shacharit you were holding. e.g. in middle of Amida, vs. Pesukei Dzimra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be **no difference between praying with or without a minyan**.

As a general rule, one may not interrupt one's prayers.

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch brings the following cases:

- During **Psukei Dzimra** one should try make the interruption between chapters, or at least between verses. He doesn't specify what to do if one interrupted for a long period of time.
- During **Shema** once can interrupt for saying Amen and the like, and then one rstarts the Pasuk one uninterrupted.
- During Shema if one interrupted by talking or going to the bathroom, one has to restart Shma from the beginning.
- During the **Amida** one may not interrupt; in cases of great need one can speed through the Amida be starting each Bracha and then saying it's ending. (If one did interrupt, IIRC one has to restart the Amida.)